# How to map column to another column value from csv file?

Tags: powershell

Suppose i have a csv file as follows:

[image: csv]

```
role    member
role1   memberA
role1   memberB
role2   memberC
role3   memberX
role3   memberY
role3   memberC
```

I want to add to a database all members to the roles on the database

```
$csvR = (Import-Csv $csvFile).role

        foreach ($Role in $csvR)
        {
            foreach ($Member in $Role) 
            {   
                & ".\AddMembers.ps1" -AddtoDatabaseOnOneServer "$Role" "$Member" "$DatabaseName" "$ServerInput"
            } 
        }
```

Will this loop recognize for example to add memberA to role1, memberB to role1, memberC to role2, etc.? in other words, is this inner loop correct: `foreach ($Member in $Role)`

Comment: Have you tried it?  The objects output by `Import-Csv` represent each row of the input CSV with a `String` property for each column.  It's not going to create any collections or do any further interpretation/association unless you instruct it to.  Further, by setting `$csvR` to `.role` you're picking off the `Role` property and discarding the rest of the object.

Comment: take a look at the `Group-Object` cmdlet help. it can group the objects from your `Import-CSV` by the `.Role` property and then you can iterate thru the resulting groups to assign the `.Member` to the `.Role`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey suppose i do this: Import-Csv "E:\foo.csv"|
Group-Object Role,Member. how do i assign the values? and after assigning the values, how do i use it in the loop?

Comment: @Cataster - take a look at what you have after you save the grouped stuff to a $Var. it'll be an array of objects & each will have a `.Group` that has all the matching objects from the CSV import in it. you can iterate thru that ... [*grin*] ///// if you replace that nasty, icky, _useless_ picture of your sample data with several lines from your source, i could do a demo of the idea. **_i won't bother if you won't bother to post usable sample data, tho._** [*frown*]

Comment: You could just do one loop and access the roles and members as properties: `$csvR = Import-Csv $csvFile; foreach ($row in $csvR) { $row.role; $row.member }`.  If your AddMembers.ps1 script only takes a single role and single member as a parameter, you will be doing some sort of iteration.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey sooo like this? $Var = Select-Object @{Name='Role'   ;Expression={$_.Values[0]}}, @{Name='Members';Expression={$_.Values[1]}}

Comment: @Lee_Dailey just pasted them in my post :)

Comment: @AdminOfThings yes my AddMembers.ps1 script only takes a single role and single member as a parameter

Comment: @Cataster - i added an answer that shows what i mean about how to use `Group-Object` for what you seem to be aiming at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a demo of how to use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to iterate thru the items in an imported CSV file by a grouped property. [*grin*]

at the `give person` line, you can either add your call to your script for each person OR gather the names of all the persons for that `.Role` and add them all at once.

```
# fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$InStuff = @'
role, member
role1, memberA
role1, memberB
role2, memberC
role3, memberX
role3, memberY
role3, memberC
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$GroupedIS = $InStuff |
    Group-Object -Property Role

foreach ($GIS_Item in $GroupedIS)
    {
    foreach ($GG_Item in $GIS_Item.Group)
        {
        'give person [ {0} ] the role [ {1} ]' -f $GG_Item.Member, $GG_Item.Role
        }
    }
```

output ...

```
give person [ memberA ] the role [ role1 ]
give person [ memberB ] the role [ role1 ]
give person [ memberC ] the role [ role2 ]
give person [ memberX ] the role [ role3 ]
give person [ memberY ] the role [ role3 ]
give person [ memberC ] the role [ role3 ]
```

Comment: nice, im trying it out!

Comment: @Cataster - it is a really nifty cmdlet ... and you can group by multiple properties ... and you use calculated properties, too. [*grin*]

Comment: @Cataster - you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]